# How to calculate the number of side of a polygon?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, polygons

[image]

I stuck on this problem. Please suggest any hint on how to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? If the polygon has $n$ sides, which angles can you calculate? If the number of sides from A to E is $k$, what other angles can you calculate?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** What is $ \angle BEA + \angle CAE $?
Express that in 2 different ways.

> $\angle BAE = \frac{360^\circ}{n}   $

> $\angle BEA + \angle CAE = 45^\circ $

> $\frac{1}{n} + \frac{ 2}{n} = \frac{ 180^\circ}{ 45^\circ }$